# How can I remove the last character of an element in an array and add it to the beginning of another element?

Tags: arrays, bash, slice, element

I have the following code:

```
white='\e[0;37m'
array=("{$white}aaaa" "{$white}aaa" "{$white}aaa")
```

Using `cuad=$( echo -e "$array[0]}" | grep -o a | wc -l` I can count the "a" in the array obtaining 4.

After doing that, using `remainder=$(( $cuad % 3 ))` I calculate the remainder dividing by 3 of the previous result.

What I want to do is:

If the remainder is equal to 1, I want to remove the last character of the element I am evaluating and add it in the beginning of the next element of the array.

If the remainder is equal to 2, I want to remove the 2 last characters of the element I am evaluating and add them in the beginning of next element of the array.

I am trying to make the number of characters in each element of the array a multiple of 3.
What I don't know is how to remove the last characters of an element and I also don't know how to add characters to the beginning of another element. In this example, the desired output for my array would be `($whiteaaa $whiteaaa $whiteaaaa)` as I don't care if the last element does not contain a multiple of 3.

Another example: `array=({$white}aaaaaaaa {$white}aaa {$white}aaa)` and the final result would be: `array=({$white}aaaaaa {$white}aaa {$white}aaaaa)` having multiples of 3 in the 2 first elements and the rest in the last one

My idea is doing something similar to this:

```
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    cuad=$( echo -e "$array[i]}" | grep -o a | wc -l
    remainder=$(( $cuad % 3 ))
    if [[ $remainder -eq 1 ]]
    then
        #remove last character of element i  
        #add that character to the element i+1
    elif [[ $remainder -eq 2 ]]
        #remove 2 last characters of element i  
        #add them to the element i+1
    fi
done
```

Comment: `"$whiteaaaa"` is the expansion of the variable `whiteaaaa`; if you want the expansion of the variable `white` followed by the string `aaaa` then you have to use `"${white}aaaa"`.

Comment: To get a useful answer we need to know what can possibly be in an element of your array. Given your example I would make the assumption that an array element is composed a sequence of any character but `a`, followed by any number of `a`; if it's correct then great, else you should provide more diversity in your sample input

Comment: In my array all elements contain and can only contain "a" as you supposed. I already edited the post with the ```${white}```

Comment: `"${white}"` is not composed of `a`... but, if it can only appear at the start of the string then you can work around that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the indexes of the array elements; then, for each element, append the exceeding number of `a` characters of the previous iteration to it, compute the exceeding ones (for the next iteration) and strip them from the current element:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
array=("X█████" "Y██" "Z███")

excess=''
for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    array[i]+=$excess

    [[ ${array[i]} =~ █+$ ]]

    case $(( ${#BASH_REMATCH} % 3 )) in
      0) excess='';;
      1) excess=█;;
      2) excess=██;;
    esac

    array[i]=${array[i]%"$excess"}
done
array[i]+=$excess
```

In this example, `array` would then become:

```bash
array=("X███" "Y███" "Z████")
```

###### Notes:

- `for i in "${!array[@]}"` loops over the indexes of the bash array `array`
- `array[i]+=$excess` appends the exceeding number of `█` of the previous iteration to the current array element.
- `[[ ${array[i]} =~ █+$ ]]` matches the longest sequence of `█` characters located at the end of the current array element; the result is stored in `BASH_REMATCH[0]`, so you can use the shortcut `$BASH_REMATCH` to get it.
- `$(( ${#BASH_REMATCH} % 3 ))` computes the modulo 3 of the length of `$BASH_REMATCH`. 
   The `case` switch defines a string representing the exceeding number of `█` (according to possible results of the modulo 3).
- `array[i]=${array[i]%"$excess"}` strips the exceeding number of `█` from the current array element.
- The last `array[i]+=$excess` is for (re)appending the exceeding number of `█` to the last array element.

Comment: That code does exactly what I need. I've tried it with several different characters and it worked until I tried using these characters in my starting array: ```array=( "██████" "███" "████")```

Is it normal for it not to work? Or should it work as well?

Comment: I only modified the content of the starting array and ```case $(( ${#BASH_REMATCH[1]} % 3 )) in 0) a='';; 1) a=█;; 2) a=██;; esac```

Comment: you have to also change the regex to `(+█)$`, and make sure that all `█` are actually the same character; copy/paste my update, it works

Comment: One more question, I had forgotten to change to ```(+█)$``` but it now works for me. But I still have a problem, (only sometimes) if I reduce the size of the terminal it doesn't work. Any idea of how to make it work? Maybe using ```tput cols``` somewhere to get the width of the screen?

Comment: I'm not sure what the terminal size has to do with the current problem?

Comment: I mean, if I reduce the size of the terminal and it doesn't print the array as it should... Sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: IMO that would be a different question; here you're not printing the array at all, just filling it; also, for filling a line of your terminal with the max multiple of 3, you can just do `cols=$(tput cols); n=$(( cols - cols % 3 ));  eval "printf █%.0s {1..$n}"; echo`

Comment: Anyway, can you explain the inside the loop part of the answer code?

Comment: Done, see the notes